# IDBKeyRange.only on a compound index in IE

Tags: indexeddb

I have the following code:

```
    this.getChildren = function (db, parentId, foldersOnly, callback, finishedCallback) {
    var transaction = db.transaction("tree", "readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("tree");

    var handleResult = function (event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
            callback(cursor.primaryKey, cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        } else {
            finishedCallback();
        }
    };

    if (foldersOnly) {
        // Only find records with the correct parentId and IsFolder == 1
        var range = IDBKeyRange.only([parentId, 1]);
        var index = objectStore.index('ParentId IsFolder');
        index.openCursor(range).onsuccess = handleResult;
    } else {
        var range = IDBKeyRange.only(parentId);
        var index = objectStore.index('ParentId');
        index.openCursor(range).onsuccess = handleResult;
    }
};
```

If foldersOnly is false then it works across all browsers. But if I pass in true then it doesn't work in IE. I just get 'Data Error' back.

I have also tried

```
var range = IDBKeyRange.bound([parentId, 1], [parentId, 1]);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:

These are how the indexes are created:

```
 treeObjectStore.createIndex("ParentId", "ParentId", { unique: false });
 treeObjectStore.createIndex("ParentId IsFolder", ['ParentId', 'IsFolder'], { unique: false });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE does not support compound indices.

Edit:

As a workaround, try creating a single property in your objects, and creating a single index on this property. In your case, try something like 'path'? You have to complicate all the bizlogic surrounding add/update, making sure to update this derived field every time, but at least it can work.

For example, as annoying as it can be, create a derived string property with a value for each object :  ParentId + ':' + (IsFolder?'1':'0').

Comment: If anyone is curious about future IE plans, all they've said is "not implementing at the moment, but on our radar" https://twitter.com/IEDevChat/status/533338659555008512 - so let's hope it makes it in IE14 or something!

Answer (score 4):

There's a new polyfill for IE that makes it behave like the standard:

https://github.com/dfahlander/idb-iegap